# What method does Librosa use to calculate Delta-MFCC?

Tags: audio-processing, mfcc, librosa

I am trying to generate the delta-MFCCs. Apparently there are several implementations. I found the "regression" formula [link here](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/Speech/docs/HTKBook/node65_mn.html). But I don't understand why Librosa uses Savitsky-Golay filter, which is a smoothing filter. I have not found any blog/article which shows the use of Sav-Gol filter for delta mfcc. And, obviously, the deltas returned by the two don't match. 
Can someone elaborate on it?